# IIS default page instead of actual site when accessed remotely

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8

IIS is returning IIS default page when accessing the site remotely while on webserver it loads fine.

I have 3 sites defined in IIS, all unique hostname binding (sitea.com, siteb.com and sitec.com). Default site is disabled.

sitea.com and siteb.com sites work fine whether accessed locally or remotely. The sitec.com site doesn't seem to load remotely but throws default IIS page. All are running on port 80. 
On the remote server hostnames are properly configured to the IP address of webserver.

`<server ip> sitea.com
<server ip> siteb.com
<server ip> sitec.com`

The siteb.com site points to the website folder of sitea.com site. This is because sitea.com has basic auth enabled while sitec.com has anonymous access.
This configuration is working as expected on webserver.

How can I troubleshoot this issue? Anything in particular I should look?

Comment: Did you add both "www." and non-www versions of the host-header to the binding?

Comment: there is only non-www and I am only trying to access via non-www.